# Is there a possibility to add a new column between two columns in a Bigquery table?

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, etl

I'm loading data into a BigQuery table, extracting from MySQL table. Now there is a addition of new column to already existing MySQL table between existing two columns. Is there any possibility to add a column between already existing columns?
If not what is the optimum way to do this operation?

Comment: What does the documentation say?

Comment: Couldn't find a specific answer.  https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-table-schemas

Comment: Create another table with the new nullable column where you want and INSERT INTO new_table (col1, col2... , coln) SELECT * FROM old_table. It's important to especify all except the new column inside the parenthesis.